# Angular - Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' in datatable search

Tags: angular, datatable

I am working on Advance Search using [@tusharghoshbd/ngx-datatable](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datatable-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcell-template%2Fcell-template.component.ts)

```
export const MERCHANT_STATUS_DATA = [
  {
    'key': 0,
    'value': 'Inactive'
  },
  {
    'key': 1,
    'value': 'Active'
  }
]
```

interface:

```
export interface Merchant {
  id?: number;
  merchant_name?: string;
  account_number?: string;
  merchant_status?: number;
  created_date?: string;
}
```

service:

```
  import { Merchant} from 'src/app/models/merchants.model';

  getAllMerchants(): Observable<Merchant[]> {
    return this.http.get<Merchant[]>(this.baseUrl + 'merchants');
  }
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, TemplateRef, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Merchant } from './merchant';
import { MerchantService } from './merchant.service';
import { MERCHANT_STATUS_DATA } from 'src/app/core/enum/merchantstatus';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('idTpl', { static: true }) idTpl!: TemplateRef<any>;
  allMerchantList: Merchant[] = [];
  data: Merchant[] = [];
  dataBK: Merchant[] = this.allMerchantList;
  columns: any[] = [];

  constructor(private merchantService: MerchantService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadDatatable();
    this.loadAllMerchants();
    this.merchantStatusData = MERCHANT_STATUS_DATA;
  }

  loadDatatable() {
    this.columns = [
      {
        key: 'id',
        title: '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i> SN.</div>',
        width: 60,
        sorting: true,
        cellTemplate: this.idTpl,
      },
      {
        key: 'merchant_name',
        title: '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Merchant</div>',
        width: 100,
        sorting: true,
      },
      {
        key: 'account_number',
        title:
          '<div class="blue"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Account No.</div>',
        width: 100,
        sorting: true,
      },
    ];
  }

  loadAllMerchants() {
    this.merchantService.getAllMerchants().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.allMerchantList = res;
      this.dataBK = this.allMerchantList;
    });
  }

  onMerchantNameSearch(value: any) {
    this.data = this.dataBK.filter(
      (row) => row.merchant_name?.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) ?? -1 > -1
    );
  }

  onAccountNumberSearch(value: any) {
    this.data = this.dataBK.filter(
      (row) => row.account_number?.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) ?? -1 > -1
    );
  }

  onMerchantStatusSearch(value: any)
  {
    this.data = this.dataBk.filter((row) => row.merchant_status == value);
  }
}
```

component/html

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="merchant_Name">Merchant Name:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      autocomplete="off"
      class="form-control"
      (input)="onMerchantNameSearch($event.target.value)"
      id="merchant_Name"
      placeholder="Merchant Name"
    />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="account_number">Account No.</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      autocomplete="off"
      class="form-control"
      (input)="onAccountNumberSearch($event.target.value)"
      id="account_number"
      placeholder="Account Number"
    />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="merchant_status">Merchant Status</label>
    <ng-select [items]="merchantStatusData"
      [selectOnTab]="true"
      [searchable]="true"
      bindValue="key"
      bindLabel="value"
      placeholder="Select Merchant Status"
      [multiple]="false"
      (change)="onMerchantStatusSearch($event.target.value)"
      [clearable]="true">
    </ng-select>
  </div>
</div>
<ngx-datatable
  tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
  [data]="allMerchantList"
  [columns]="columns"
  [options]="options"
>
  <ngx-caption> Title </ngx-caption>

  <ng-template
    #addressTpl
    let-row
    let-rowIndex="rowIndex"
    let-columnValue="columnValue"
  >
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #idTpl let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-row="row">
    {{ rowIndex + 1 }}
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable>
```

console.log(this.allMerchantList);  and

console.log(this.dataBk);

gives:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "merchant_name": "Appiah",
        "account_number": "332222",
        "merchant_status": 1,
        "created_date": "2022-01-24T12:51:08.19",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "merchant_name": "Kwesi",
        "account_number": "554444",
        "merchant_status": 1,
        "created_date": "2022-01-25T16:43:41.873",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "merchant_name": "fggffgfgfg",
        "account_number": "455654",
        "merchant_status": 1,
        "created_date": "2022-01-25T16:46:20.77",
    }
]
```

I got this error in component.html

> Object is possibly 'null'

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

> Error occurs in the template of component MerchantsComponent.

Then I changed (input)="onMerchantNameSearch($event.target.value)" to (input)="onMerchantNameSearch($event.target.value)", the error is no more there but it's not implementing the search action. Ideally as the user types in the text input, it suppose to reflect the result in the datatable, not that's not hppening.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

The

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using this approach and you need to update the allMerchantList array to update your data table

```
loadAllMerchants() {
 this.getAllMerchants().subscribe((res: any) => {
   this.allMerchantList = res;
   this.dataBK = res;
 });
}

onMerchantNameSearch(value: string) {
  this.allMerchantList = this.dataBK.filter(
   (row) => row.merchant_name?.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
}

onAccountNumberSearch(value: any) {
  this.allMerchantList = this.dataBK.filter(
    (row) => row.account_number?.toLowerCase().includes(value)
  );
}
```

check this [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7dtej?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks. How do I also make with onMerchantStatusSearch which is a @ng-select/ng-select dropdown. I have updated my code

Comment: May I know how many statuses could a Merchant have?

Comment: I have updated the code with merchantStatusData and MERCHANT_STATUS_DATA.     0 = Inactive  and 1 = Active.  Though it can change in the future, and be more than that

Comment: I've just found that when searching with more than one field the result won't be right, let me fix that for you on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7dtej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), and please mark my answer as accepted if it is.

Comment: you can check the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7dtej?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) there's now only one function to do the job

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241519/discussion-between-midowu-and-troudi-ghaith).